# using quote_literal while insertin in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, sql-injection, plpgsql

I am new to `plpgsql` and seems so confusing. I want to test the strength of `quote_literal` against SQL injection attacks, so I try to `INSERT`.  I am not an expert in SQL injection attacks either, I just try to recreate examples I see.

If I use `quote_literal` in my code, as below, the names are saved with `'`. So, I call `select __a_inj('hey');` then `'hey'` is saved. Not `hey`.

On the other hand, if I call`select __a_inj('drop table deleteme');` I always get `'drop table deleteme'` saved whether I use quote_literal or not.

```
 CREATE  FUNCTION __a_inj(creator text) RETURNS integer   
  AS $query$
  DECLARE ii ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO deleteme(name) VALUES(quote_literal($1)) RETURNING id into ii;
    return ii;

END;
$query$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How should I use `quote_literal`, or any other function to defend against SQL injection attacks and not mess things up?

(some things that bug me 
why are there so little examples of inserting? 
why cant I use `EXECUTE` with insert. I keep getting errors, no matter my syntax)

Comment: No you don't need that there. You only need it for dynamic SQL

Comment: yes, but the input is by the user, so by default it can be malicious. right?

Comment: No, not with the way you use the parameter

Comment: from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html) : `As each expression and SQL command is first executed in the function, the PL/pgSQL interpreter parses and analyzes the command to create a prepared statement, using the SPI manager's SPI_prepare function. `.  So I am covered because this is translated to a prepared statement? Because at first I thought that only `format` and `quote_literal/nullable` are protecting you, but you only need those with `EXECUTE`. I think that is the whole deal. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you don't:

```
t=# \sf __a_inj (text)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION postgres.__a_inj(creator text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
  DECLARE ii ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO deleteme(name) VALUES(creator) RETURNING id into ii;
    return ii;

END;
$function$

t=# select __a_inj('null);drop table deleteme');
 __a_inj
---------

(1 row)

t=# select * from deleteme ;
           name            | id
---------------------------+----
 null);drop table deleteme |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So, this `insert` syntax is by default string enough against SQL injection? -Also, I am a noob, so please elaborate a little more on the `select __a_inj('null);drop table deleteme');` part. Why that syntax?

Comment: not insert, but using an argument in function and plain, not dynamic SQL do, like prepared statement... the syntax was demostrating SQL injection not working

Comment: Oh ok, cool. I though this is dynamic because the input is by the user. What would be dynamic `INSERT` then? A syntax with `INSERT`, `IF`, `EXECUTE` and user input?

Comment: with `execute 'insert blah...'`